# schemaTypes in sanity io

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, content-management-system, sanity

I am facing problem in schemaTypes of Sanity io
All the details are mentioned below
Any problem regarding the question U can ask me

**userSchema.js**

```
    name:'abouts',
    title:'Abouts',
    type: 'document',
    fields:[
        {
            name:'title',
            title:'Title',
            type:'string'
        },
        {
            name:'description',
            title:'Description',
            type:'string'
        },
        {
            name:'imgUrl',
            title:'ImgUrl',
            type: 'image',
            options: {
              hotspot: true,
            },
        },

    ]
}
```

**schema.js**

```
import createSchema from 'part:@sanity/base/schema-creator'
import schemaTypes from 'all:part:@sanity/base/schema-type'
import { userSchema } from './userSchema'

export default createSchema({
  
  name: 'default',
  types: schemaTypes.concat([userSchema]),
})
```

Now, **schemaTypes** is an OBJECT as we can check from "typeof" operator, I dont understand how can we use **.concat()** with an Object, like .concat() is an array function which can be applied with Array, So how **schemaTypes.concat([userSchema])** is working correctly??

Please help me regarding this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript you will never get `'array'` back from `typeof`. `typeof` will return `'object'` for any non-primitive other than functions (and the primitive `null`).

What I expect you are looking for is the `Array.isArray()` method. Logging `Array.isArray(schemaTypes)` should return `true`, meaning that `schemaTypes` is in fact an array and can use the `.concat()` method.